# How to receive differences of intersecting SpatialLines in R?

Tags: r, intersection, difference

How to receive a list of SpatialLines of the differences of the intersecting SpatialLines only?

create SpatialLines:

```
#from the sp vignette:
l1 = cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(3,2,2,4))
rownames(l1) = letters[1:4]
l2 = cbind(c(2,2,3,3),c(3,2,2,5))
rownames(l2) = letters[1:4]
l3 = cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,2,1))
rownames(l3) = letters[1:4]
Sl1 = Line(l1)
Sl2 = Line(l2)
Sl3 = Line(l3)
Ll1 = Lines(list(Sl1), ID="a")
Ll2 = Lines(list(Sl2), ID="b")
Ll3 = Lines(list(Sl3), ID="c")
Sl = SpatialLines(list(Ll1,Ll2,Ll3))
```

resulting SpatialLines ("Sl") show intersections and differences.
Receiving the differences of all SpatialLines of the list can be achieved like this:

```
C = combn(1:length(Sl),2)
C2 = cbind(C,C[2:1,])
MyDiffs = apply(C2, 2, function(x){gDifference(Sl[x[1]], Sl[x[2]])})
```

see [spacedman´s answer to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193881/how-to-apply-functions-iteratively-to-spatiallines-in-r)

Looking for the differences of the intersecting SpatialLines only.
I was thinking about something like if the condition `gIntersect=TRUE` then apply `gDifference()`. However, I can´t find a way to do that in R.
Maybe there´s a smarter solution...

**Edit:**
The answer of [bogdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37415043/5620248) works, but all differences appear twice. 
Manipulating the matrix in a way that the lower triangular part get removed led to the result that some doubled differences are kept while others get removed.

```
library("reshape2")
# compute intersection matrix by ID
intersections <- gIntersects(Sl, byid=TRUE)
# set lower triangular part of matrix NA
intersections[lower.tri(intersections, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
# melt matrix into edge list (+remove NA)
intersections <- melt(intersections, na.rm=TRUE)
# compute differences
MyDiffs = apply(intersections, 1, function(x){gDifference(Sl[x[1]], Sl[x[2]])})
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `gIntersects` with `byid=T` and the `melt` function in `reshape2`:

```
library("reshape2")
# compute intersection matrix by ID
intersections <- gIntersects(Sl, byid=T)
# melt matrix into edge list
intersections <- melt(intersections)
# keep only intersecting lines, remove diagonals
intersections <- subset(intersections, Var1 != Var2 & value)
# compute differences
MyDiffs = apply(intersections, 1, function(x){gDifference(Sl[x[1]], Sl[x[2]])})
```

Comment: It works, but all differences appear twice. Any suggestions how to create each difference only once?

Comment: In order to receive only one line per difference `gLineMerge()` can be applied. However this is an additional step that might be avoidable by advanced data mining

Comment: Try subsetting on `Var1 < Var2` to just get each intersection happening once.